# PHP ini_set memory limit

Tags: php, memory, memory-limit

When we use ini_set like below in code, will memory limit be the same for all other codes? or only valid for in which code we added ?

`ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');`

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is only working for the file where it is written.
Best way to change settings for multiple phps in the same folder are:

## 1. creating a file named ".htaccess" with the line

> php_value memory_limit '512M'

Keep in mind, this only works, if you server configuration allowes "AllowOverride" directive for this directory

## 2. adding a own php with your config options as [auto-prepend-file](http://php.net/manual/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file)

You can do this in php.ini.

## 3. changing value of "memory_limit" directly in you php.ini

but this will take affect to ALL php-files you are running

Comment: i dont want to change  the default memory_limit  ,just want to incerease it for specific php file , so when i add ini_set('memory_limit', '512M'); , then only for this file memory will be used to 512. other php file will use default limit . this is what i undertand.

Comment: Yes thats correct, ini_set only affects THIS php and all files wich are included from this file.

Comment: 1. This solution is tied exclusively to Apache httpd. 2. This solution is slow. 3. This is The Right Way™ to do it (defined as: most portable, with best performance).

Comment: you can change the link from `php.net/manual/de/` to `php.net/manual/en/`

Answer (score 1):

It depends where you are adding.

If in a `specific script` then till that script is running. If setting at `application level` then it will be set for that specific application.

Comment: if i add it in test.php then when we execute it , memory will be setted to 512M then after exiting from script , default memory limit(not 512M) will be used for other php file, right?