# How to insert large JSON file to database with PHP

Tags: php, json

So, I have a large JSON file and I want to insert data from that file to MySQL database. I can only use PHP 5.6 and can't change php.ini file.

When I'm using `json_decode()`, I get error, that there is to much memory to allocate. So I searched for some kind of library and I found this [library](https://github.com/salsify/jsonstreamingparser) and I'm using it like that:

```
set_time_limit(300);
$listener = new \JsonStreamingParser\Listener\InMemoryListener();
$stream = fopen('data/stops.json', 'r');
try {
    $parser = new \JsonStreamingParser\Parser($stream, $listener);
    $parser->parse();
    fclose($stream);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    fclose($stream);
    throw $e;
}
var_dump($listener->getJson());
```

But I still get that annoying error about momory:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 72 bytes) in
>   SOME/PATH/TO/vendor/salsify/json-streaming-parser/src/Parser.php on
>   line 516

I have no clue how to obtain my JSON file. So I'm looking for some advice, or someone who can help me to write a code that will be responsible for converting JSON file to array, so I colud insert data from that array to database. Also I'm not looking for one time solution, becouse I need to parse that JSON a least one per day.

Here is the whole JSON file: [JSON](http://91.244.248.19/dataset/c24aa637-3619-4dc2-a171-a23eec8f2172/resource/cd4c08b5-460e-40db-b920-ab9fc93c1a92/download/stops.json), the structure looks like this:

```
{
    "2017-07-26":
        {
            "lastUpdate":"2017-07-26 07:07:01",
            "stops":[
                {
                    "stopId":32640,
                    "stopCode":null,
                    "stopName":null,
                    "stopShortName":"2640",
                    "stopDesc":"Amona",
                    "subName":"2640",
                    "date":"2017-07-26",
                    "stopLat":54.49961,
                    "stopLon":18.44532,
                    "zoneId":null,
                    "zoneName":null,
                    "stopUrl":"",
                    "locationType":null,
                    "parentStation":null,
                    "stopTimezone":"",
                    "wheelchairBoarding":null,
                    "virtual":null,
                    "nonpassenger":null,
                    "depot":null,
                    "ticketZoneBorder":null,
                    "onDemand":null,
                    "activationDate":"2017-07-25"
                },
                {...},
                {...}
            ]
        }
}
```

Comment: Is this a one off? or is this going to happen regularly?

Comment: you can try with a `.htaccess` file with this in it `php_value memory_limit 200M` (example for 200M). I think it depends on your config, but worked for me

Comment: regularlym, at least one time per day

Comment: yeah, but what when I will need more and more memory to parse my array, I'm looking for some long shot solution, becosue im' not sure how large my JSON file will be in the future and I don't want to set that limit to unlimited o something liek that

Comment: you could also read the file line-by-line but that will force you to stop and start via regular expressions - which will result in spaghetti code, you will pretty much be forced to re-invent the JSON wheel

Comment: You might wish to use something like this: https://github.com/kuma-giyomu/JSONParser/tree/master/package but ideally i'd say preprocess the data on your work pc where you have full control into batches and dispatch those to the server.

Comment: if your JSON file is a repeated structure of similar elements, you can modify your script to be able to process multiple files, and split your JSON..

Comment: Yeah, I also thought about reading file line-by-line, maybe I will do that, but for now I'm looking for some kind more universal and faster solution ;)

Comment: @Kaddath, that's actually a good idea, I will go to search something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the option via `ini_set` : http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

```
ini_set('memory_limit','16M');
```

taken from https://davidwalsh.name/increase-php-memory-limit-ini_set

---

alternatively, you can use a .htaccess file :

```
php_value memory_limit '512M'
```

credit goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/42578190/351861

Comment: To be honses, I'm a little bit supprised, I have some cheap hosting server and they blocked me to edit php.ini file but that trick with .htaccess works; but I'm still curious how can I somehwo chunk my json file and maybe in parts convert it to `json_decode()`